# Error validating Newline delimited JSON Document

Tags: json

The Newline delimited JSON file parsing correctly for below JSON Structure.

```
{
    "name": "Honeywell",
    "BOM": "12 GENUINE MIX RESISTOR KIT 150PCS 30\n1/21/4W + MIX zelatin CAPACITOR KIT\n3",
    "url": "http://fairchild.com",
    "image": "http://fairchild.com/over.jpg",
    "ThresholdRange": "2M",
    "Peak": "8",
    "date": "2003-04-01",
    "DeadTime": "15M"
},
```

But As soon i am adding below line it is throwing Error.

```
{
    "name": "VishayElectronics.com",
    "BOM": "12 GENUINE MIX RESISTOR KIT 150PCS 30\n1/21/4W + MIX power CAPACITOR KIT\n3",
    "url": "http://vishay.com",
    "image": "http://vishay/to.jpg",
    "ThresholdRange": "10M",
    "Peak": "8",
    "date": "2011-06-06",
    "DeadTime": "6M"
}

i am validating using https://jsonlint.com/

Error: Parse error on line 10:
...adTime": "15M"}{ "name": "VishayEl
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

May someone please help me what changes i should make to resolve error.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost a "," between your first object and the second one.

Comment: Thanks Pylon, even after adding ",".... it is throwing error as Expecting 'EOF', got ','

Comment: Could you try to add a "," ending line for each object?